# My django login form isn't working, says 'request' has no atrribute 'method'

Tags: python, django

When I try to login on my django site, I get this error:
AttributeError at /login/
'User' object has no attribute 'method'
What is the problem? I'm fairly sure it was working yesterday, and now it isn't.

[image: This is the error]

This is my login view:

```
from django import forms
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

class LoginForm (forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField()
    password = forms.CharField()

def login (request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
#           username = request.POST['username']
#           password = request.POST['password']
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None and user.is_active:
                login(user)
                return redirect ("/login/success")
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
    else:
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
    return render (request, 'login.html', {'form':form})
```

Comment: `login()` is recursively calling itself when successful - that can't be right.  Perhaps that call was supposed to be to the `login` that you imported from `django.contrib.auth`?

Comment: you'll have to change your ```login``` function to a different name because it's conflicting with the ```django.contrib.auth.login``` function that you're importing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling your function with user as the param instead of a request. Rename your function, the imported Django's login or the way you import it.

Also, you are missing the request param, you should do `login(request, user)`.

Use one of these options:

```
def my_login (request):  # fix the necessary urls also
    if request.method == 'POST':
        .....
        login(request, user)
```

or

```
from django.contrib import auth

.....

user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)
if user is not None and user.is_active:
    auth.login(request, user)
```

or

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login as django_login        

.....

user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
if user is not None and user.is_active:
    django_login(request, user)
```